# Why aren't values in an array shown in console logs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get image dimensions.  here is my attempt with `.load`

```
    function checkgallery_imagesize(src) {
          var dimensions = [];

          $("<img/>").load(function(){
                dimensions.push(this.width);
                dimensions.push(this.height); 
            }).attr("src", src);

          return dimensions;
         }

var src = 'example.png';
dimensions = checkgallery_imagesize(src);

console.log(dimensions[0]); //width;
console.log(dimensions[1]); //height;
```

When i use `console.log(dimensions)`.  I see the dimensions in the array but i can't access the array.  `dimensions[0]` and `dimensions[1]` are both undefined

Comment: Your console logs are running before the load function completes. Move them inside it.

Comment: i need the console.log outside the function.  I'm going to be using width and height outside the function.

Comment: Then you'll need to arrange your program to wait for `checkgallery_imagesize()`. Promise or await or whatever.

Comment: Also you should move the `var dimension` declaration outside the function. As the error says 'dimension is undefined' where you are accessing (console.log)